# Putting together a system of equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions

Someone helped me out with a problem a while back. Bout a year ago. But I still don't know how he derived the equation from or how he got it.

I have two equations.

$f/(f-n) = c$

$-nf/(f-n) = d$

We need to solve for $$f and $n$ as a system because $2$ equations, $2$ unknowns:

from $f/(f-n) = c \to n = f - f/c$

Plugging it in the other equation:

$n\cdot(d-f) = f\cdot d$, <--- How did he get this part?

$(f - f/c)\cdot(d-f) = f\cdot d$,

$f\cdot d-f\cdot f-f\cdot d/c+f\cdot f/c = f\cdot d$,

$f\cdot(f\cdot(1/c-1)-d/c) = 0$

How do I solve for f? if $ n = -d/c $

which equation above do I plug into

Comment: Easier is to "divide" second by first, we get $-n=d/c$. Now finding $f$ is easy.

Comment: hey Andre, which equation do I put -n = d/c into?

Comment: Note that my division is OK only if $c\ne 0$. Substituting in the first looks better. We get $f=fc-nc=fc+d$, so $f-fc=d$ and therefore $f=\frac{d}{1-c}$. (We need $c\ne 1$.)

Comment: Ok I got it. thxu

Comment: You are welcome. The other way is OK too, just takes more work. The division trick, if we see it, is very quick.